# Why is dropdown value not being passed in ASP classic?

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to pass along the value from the newbrand dropdown to the next page (addbrand.asp), however, it is not working, and will just be blank. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this?

```vbs
<form class="form" method="post">
<table>
<%i = 0%>
<% for each brand in Brands %>
    <tr><td><B><%=brand%></B></td>  
    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-small" value="Delete" onclick="document.location='deletebrand.asp?brand=<%=brands(i)%>&client=<%=clientcno%>&id=<%=clientid%>'"></td></tr>
    <%i = i + 1%>
<% next %>
<tr><td colspan=2><hr></td></tr>
<tr><td><B>Add:</B></td>
<td>
<select name="newbrand">
<option value=""></option>
<% for each brand in newbrands %>
    <option value="<%=brand%>"><%=brand%></option>
<% next %>
</select>
<%
If Request.Form("newbrand") <> "" then
    newbrand = Request.Form("newbrand")
End If
%>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-small" value="Add"
 onclick="document.location='addbrand.asp?brand=<%=newbrand%>&client=<%=clientcno%>&id=<%=clientid%>'");">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You're not using your `form` properly. Set your `form target` attribute to *addbrand.asp* and the data will be transferred properly, allowing you to intercept it on that page using `Request.Form`.

Comment: 1. There's an extra `"` in the "onclick" attribute. 2. Why are you doing this in a JavaScript-only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press the button 'add', it should send the selected 'newbrand' to the addbrand.asp?

Now you pass on the server-side value, you need to send the client-side value. Change the onclick to something like

`document.location='addbrand.asp?brand=' + document.getElementsByName("newbrand")[0].options[document.getElementsByName("newbrand")[0].selectedIndex].value + '&client=...`

It gets a bit messy due to the inline Javascript. It's easier to assign an ID to the select element, then you can use document.getElementById which makes it a bit more simple:

`document.location='addbrand.asp?brand=' + document.getElementById("newbrand").options[document.getElementById("newbrand").selectedIndex].value + '&client=...`